# Как в JS передать в функцию опцинальный параметр являющийся фунцкцией?

Tags: javascript

Как правильно объявить функцию `updateParam()` чтобы параметр `successCallback` был опционален?

Тоесть чтобы обы следующих вызова функции были корректны:

1.

```
updateParam("myName", "myValue");
```

2.

```
updateParam("myName", "myValue", function(){
    console.log("Callback");
});
```

Моя функция:

```
function updateParam(parameterName, value, successCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php?c=params&a=updateParam',
        ///....
        success: function (data) {
            var response = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (response != true) {
                console.log(data);
                ShowError();
            }else{
                successCallback();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Интересует есть ли способ декларирования фунции с опциональным параметром, а не простая проверка существует ли объект. 
Либо же, в крайнем случае, проверка является ли этот объект функцией.

Comment: Проверить, если successCallback равен udefined, значит не задан. Если нет - вызывать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В ES2015 можно использовать [параметры по умолчанию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

```
function updateParam(parameterName, value, successCallback=function(){}) {
```

**Важно:** данный метод помогает только если параметр не будет передан при вызове. Но он никак не поможет, если в функцию будет передан параметр не ожидаемого типа.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
function updateParam(parameterName, value, successCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php?c=params&a=updateParam',
        ///....
        success: function (data) {
            var response = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (response != true) {
                console.log(data);
                ShowError();
            }
            else if( typeof(successCallback) === 'function' ){
                    successCallback();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: здесь нет смысла в `call` - достаточно обычного вызова `successCallback()`

Comment: Спасибо, подтянул. Согласен - избыточно.

Comment: Ответ даже не выполняется, вертно имелось ввиду typeof (successCallback) === 'function' ?

Comment: @koks_rs, важно направление :)

Comment: Конечно. Писал по памяти прям в текущем редакторе. Спасибо, поправил.

Answer (score 1):

```
  ...
} else if (successCallback) {
  successCallback();
}
```

Comment: не самый элегантный способ. А если кто-то по ошибке передаст в мою функцию стороку?

Comment: @koks_rs, значит он сам виноват

Comment: @koks_rs - вернемся к этому вопросу, когда мы увидим проверку типов первых двух параметров.

Comment: @Igor, проверка первых двух параметров не столь важна, в моем конкретном случае.